# How can I get coupled data in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm new at Postgres and I want to find coupled data.

```
SELECT id, email, count(*) AS total FROM public."mails" GROUP BY email HAVING total > 1 ORDER BY email ASC
```

I got SQL code like this but I got an error.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your error message is missing!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Using your statement, I get this error:

```
ERROR: column "mails.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 8
```

From https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/postgresql-where-order-by-and-group-by-clauses:

> The PostgreSQL GROUP BY clause is used with SELECT statements to accumulate identical data into groups. This is used to reduce the redundancy in the result. The GROUP BY clause works with aggregates functions, like SUM(), COUNT() and also without aggregate functions.

All selected columns must be part of the group by statement.

Solution tested on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/47beb

```
create table mails (id integer, email varchar(100));
insert into mails (id, email) values (1, 'albert');
insert into mails (id, email) values (1, 'albert');
insert into mails (id, email) values (2, 'isaac');
```

**SQLs statement** (with both id and email column included):

```
SELECT id, email, count(*)
FROM mails 
GROUP BY id, email HAVING count(*) > 1 
ORDER BY email ASC
```